# Replace a dynamic file extension with a fixed file extension

Tags: shell, rename, replace

I need to replace dynamic file extensions which contain timestamp for certain date with a fixed file extension.

For example,

```
08242016G0040156.ZIP.20160907141452  
09042016SHOC0003.ZIP.20160904044504
```

I need these to be replaced with `08242016G0040156.ZIP` and `09042016SHOC0003.ZIP` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash, a simple loop with some string manipulation

```
for f in ./*.ZIP.*
do
   mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

`"${f%.*}"` removes everything after the last `.` (inclusive) in the string in `$f`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for filename in $(find . -name '*ZIP*'); do mv $filename $(echo $filename | sed 's|\(.*\)\.ZIP.*|\1.ZIP|g') ; done
```

Comment: see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` based `rename` command:

```
$ touch 08242016G0040156.ZIP.20160907141452 09042016SHOC0003.ZIP.20160904044504

$ rename -n 's/\.\d+$//' *ZIP*
rename(08242016G0040156.ZIP.20160907141452, 08242016G0040156.ZIP)
rename(09042016SHOC0003.ZIP.20160904044504, 09042016SHOC0003.ZIP)
```

`-n` option is for dry run. If the renaming is fine, remove it for actual renaming

If the files can be in multiple sub-directories, use `find`

```
find -name '*ZIP*' -exec rename -n 's/\.\d+$//' {} +
```

If there are characters other than digits after last `.` use

```
rename -n 's/\.[^.]+$//' *ZIP*
```